# creating UIView prevents IBAction being sent

Tags: ios, uiview, ibaction

I am trying to draw a UIView to the screen while simultaneously moving other UI elements out of it's way. Both events are triggered by the same UISwitch. When I don't draw the UIView the UI elements move as they should, but when I call the action to draw the UIView, the UI elements don't move as they should. I have no idea why this is happening, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the function that adds and removes the view:

```
- (IBAction)showHideMyNewView:(UISwitch *)sender {
if (_mySwitch.on) {
    [self.view addSubview:myNewView];
}
else {
    [myNewView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Here is the function that moves the other UI elements to make room for the UIView:

```
  - (IBAction)moveUIElementsForPainIntensityView:(id)sender {
_mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
if (_mySwitch.on) {
    [_labelOne moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 350) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelTwo moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 400) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelThree moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 450) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelFour moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 500) duration:0.5 option:0];
}
else {
    [_labelOne moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 150) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelTwo moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 200) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelThree moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 250) duration:0.5 option:0];
    [_labelFour moveTo:CGPointMake(50, 300) duration:0.5 option:0];
}}
```

Comment: have you linked the moveUIElementsForPainIntensityView action method to the switch.Try keeping a breakpoint at this method to check if its getting fired or not.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, try turning it off to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, rdelmar that was it!